# Why is my zipline schedule_function not working for monthly schedule? backtest is always running on a daily basis

Tags: function, schedule, zipline

I am trying to schedule my rebalance function in zipline 1.4.1, however instead of running on a monthly schedule my backtest is running daily.

Actual code:

```
#%%
import zipline.api as zapi
from zipline import run_algorithm
import pandas as pd

#%%
def initialize(context):
    zapi.schedule_function(
        rebalance,
        algo.date_rules.month_start(),
        algo.time_rules.market_open(hours=2)
    )

def rebalance(context, data):
    print(f"rebalancing at {zapi.get_datetime()}")

def analyze(context, perf):
    print('We are now analyzing')

#%%
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2010-1-3', tz='UTC')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2010-4-3', tz='UTC')

result = run_algorithm(
        start = start_date,
        end = end_date,
        initialize=initialize,
        handle_data=rebalance,
        # benchmark_returns=benchmarkReturns,
        capital_base= 10000,
        analyze=analyze,
        data_frequency='daily',
        bundle='csv-bundle')
```

backtest result:

```
rebalancing at 2010-01-04 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-04 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-05 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-06 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-07 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-08 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-11 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-12 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-13 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-14 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-15 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-19 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-20 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-21 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-22 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-25 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-26 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-27 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-28 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-01-29 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-02-01 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-02-01 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-02-02 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-02-03 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-02-04 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-02-05 21:00:00+00:00
rebalancing at 2010-02-08 21:00:00+00:00
```

I tried to downgrade zipline to version 1.3.0 and got the same result. Does anyone got the same issue? and is there is any fix for this? your kind reply is appreciated.

Comment: Have you had any success with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I don't think schedule_function works with zipline. run_algorithm

I worked around it by creating a function:

```
def monthly_cal(cal_name,start,end):
xnys=get_calendar(cal_name)
xnys_cal= xnys.sessions_in_range(start,end)
df=pd.DataFrame(index=xnys_cal)
df['month']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).month
trading_days=df['month'][df['month'] != df['month'].shift(-1)].index
return trading_days
```

and load it in the initialize

```
context.available_dates=monthly_cal('XNYS',start,end)
```

and check this condition in handle_data
if context.get_datetime().date() in context.available_dates: